# Paypal IPN data receiveing on localhost using ngrok

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Does paypal send IPN data to localhost when accessing via internet using `ngrok`? I tested it with Payza and it successfully sent the IPN data and I could insert the data into the database. But when tried with paypal, I am not receiving any data. Does paypal not send to localhost's accessed via internet using ngrok? Or, is there another problem in my code?

I am successfully getting redirected to success page after payment but the data is not inserted in my database.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom PayPal Test Integration</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="shubhamjha900@gmail.com">
        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="12345">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.50">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://229a1c8a.ngrok.io/sites/paypal6/failed.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://229a1c8a.ngrok.io/sites/paypal6/success.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://229a1c8a.ngrok.io/sites/paypal6/ipn.php' />
        <!-- Display the payment button. -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ipn.php

```
<?php
$dbname = "codexworld";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbhost = "localhost";

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

// STEP 1: Read POST data
// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    else
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO payments(user_id)VALUES(1)");
    $stmt-> execute();

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

Please help me guys. I am stuck on this since a few days. I really need to implement it and get through. Please help!!